# Albert-Barabasi model

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, dynamical-systems, weak-convergence, random-graphs

According to Remco Hofstad's book on Random graphs, for the Albert Barabasi model, the degree of the i^{th} node diverges almost surely (Exercise 8.8 of the first volume).

But isn't this counter-intuitive since the asymptotic distribution is a power law ?

I mean to ask how come the proportion of vertices having degree 1, for example, can be so high, asymptotically, when each node's degree diverges almost surely ?

Comment: Can you perhaps recall the model and basic facts relevant to the question? For those who don't have the book?

Comment: The Albert Barabasi model is the following: start with two nodes connected to each other through an edge. At each point of time, a new node arrives, and links to one of the existing nodes in the network, with probability proportional to the degree of that node. This model explains the power law distribution that is found in real-world networks. It is a very important model, and basically launched the field of network science two decades ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no contradiction between the two observations. More precisely, the two observations are:

> For any fixed vertex $v_i$, as time goes to infinity, the degree of $v_i$ diverges

and

> At any fixed time, a large fraction of vertices have degree $1$. (More generally, the degree distribution at any fixed time follows a power law.)

(Note that in order to get vertices of degree $1$, we should be looking at the $m=1$ case of the model, giving us a tree; in general, the degree distribution still follows a power law, but all degrees are at least $m$.)

Preferential attachment models are also called "the rich get richer" models. Extending that analogy, you can think of degree distributions in the Barabási–Albert model as a "pyramid scheme".

- At any time $t$, a large fraction of the vertices in the system are "newcomers", and still have the degree we started with. It's possible that some vertices have been around for a long time, and still unluckily have low degree, but most vertices that have been around for a long time are "rich, and getting richer".
- If we skip ahead to time $100t$ (for example), then the vertices we saw at time $t$ are just $1\%$ of the vertices in the system now. It is still true that a large fraction of the vertices in the system have low degree, but for the most part, that refers to the vertices that have appeared recently. The $1\%$ of vertices that had already appeared by time $t$ generally have pretty high degree, because they've had at least $99t$ time steps in which their degree could increase. (It's possible that some have gotten unlucky, but most haven't.)

In general, as time increases, the very old vertices tend to be "rich" (and have high degree), but most vertices are not very old. This explains the power law distribution of degrees. However, for any fixed vertex $v_i$, if we wait long enough, eventually $v_i$ will become a very old vertex. (At time $100i$, it is in the top $1\%$ of vertices by age, so we expect it to have pretty high degree.)

The reason that this works out for the vertices, while pyramid schemes generally don't work out for humans, is that the number of vertices grows without limit, whereas pyramid schemes aren't able to attract infinitely many people.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very nicely explained. Seems like the 'rich gets richer' terminology is bit of a misnomer for this model. It should be called 'old gets richer'.

Comment: The old get... moderately rich. Because of the focus of your question, I haven't touched on the other side of that saying, which is really about the *high* end of the power law. Take the vertex with the highest degree at time $t$; it's likely to be one of the highest-degree vertices at time $100t$ as well, and have a much higher degree then than it did at time $t$. Low-degree vertices at time $t$ will generally have a decently high degree at time $100t$, but they'll be beaten out by vertices that were doing better at time $t$, and even by some lucky newcomers.

Comment: Are there other models you are aware of, that display the 'old get moderately rich' phenomena ? Taking sublinear or superlinear attachment rules generally destroys the power law at the tail, as far as I am aware (exponential tails), while other models start displaying the condensation phenomena (one node takes almost all the edges), right ?

Comment: Even completely non-preferential attachment (for $m=1$, a [random recursive tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_recursive_tree)) will see that kind of behavior. At any given time, half the vertices in a random recursive tree are leaves; however, because attachment is non-preferential, if we go from time $t$ to time $100t$, each vertex gets an average of $99$ new vertices, following an approximately Poisson distribution. It's still true that with high probability, the degree of a fixed vertex goes off to infinity.